# Error on using PKCS#11 Driver Library acospkcs11.dll in Chilkat PKCS11 for .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, pkcs#11, chilkat

I am successfully using Pkcs11Interop 5.1.2 library for digital signing using PKCS#11 Driver Library acospkcs11.dll.
But when using the ChilkatDnCore 9.50.97 library (License purchased), when I call the following code:

```
Chilkat.Global glob = new Chilkat.Global();
bool success = glob.UnlockBundle("XXXX");
Chilkat.Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Chilkat.Pkcs11();
pkcs11.SharedLibPath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/CTS/Desktop Suite/native_libs/acospkcs11.dll";
pkcs11.Initialize();
```

I get an error:
`has exited with code 3221225725 (0xc00000fd) 'Stack overflow'`
or
`has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'`

Please help me solve this problem.

I ran this code in the console app in x86 mode.

Answer (score -1):

Even though you said it worked with the `Pkcs11Interop 5.1.2 library`, I still think it's likely the problem is happening within the `acospkcs11.dll`.

Try this: Turn on verbose logging like this:

```
pkcs11.VerboseLogging = true;
```

Then also set the `DebugLogFilePath` like this:

```
pkcs11.DebugLogFilePath = "c:/temp/debugLog.txt";
```

Then re-run your code to reproduce the error and examine the contents of the `debugLog.txt`.

Comment: `code`Initialize:
    DllDate: Jan 26 2024
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.97
    UnlockPrefix: QSYSTM
    UnlockStatus: 2
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: Visual C++ 9.0 (32-bit)
    VerboseLogging: 1
    pkcs11_initialize:
        loadPkcs11Dll_windows:
            (leaveContext 15ms)
        getPkcs11Functions:`code`  This is the whole log